# Reverse engineering a precompiled website

Tags: asp.net

Hi i am in need of your assistance. I have a precompiled website project and now i cant see the source files hence i cant edit my web project.I am only left with the aspx files which when i try viewing them i get a message "This is a marker file generated by the prrecompilation tool and should not be deleted." I tried deleting the PrecompileApp.config file plus some dll files in the bin folder marked 'App_Web3610tfd...something like that but the website is still uneditable. Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best solution here isn't a technology solution. Track down all the people who were ever invovled in this project and see if their machines have the source code.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use tools like Telerik's [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) or Red-Gate's [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). Unfortunately you're never going to get the full project back. You're going to get decompiled files that were converted from IL to code. This doesn't generally yield code that is nice and readable. You've got the worst case scenario, pre-compiled and using non-updatable .aspx/.ascx files. It will take a lot of stitching of code to get it back and make sense of it so be prepared to spend a bit of time. Many function calls may be renamed because the compiler doesn't necessarily keep them with nice names (it doesn't need to since the resulting code isn't run by a human). Other than this, there aren't many options without going to a decompiler.